# MCP3909 Energy metering IC , How to use the HFOUT in it?

Tags: measurement

I'm using the Microchip MCP3909 Energy metering IC, How to use the HFOUT in it ?

note:
HFout supplies a frequency output proportional to the average active real power .

This frequency should be sent to the meter on HFOUT pin which access a Timer/Counter in MC and according to number of Pulses I should measure power and use it

The problem is that I couldn't reach the correct relation which determine each pulse represents what amount of watt?

**Documents:**
[MCP3909 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22025a.pdf)
[Reference Design User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51643a.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Reference Design User's Guide, page 42:

> "The meter constant is typically given in units of impulses per kilo-watt hour. As an
>   example, the calibration output frequency of CF, METER_CONSTANT =
>   3200 imp/kWh or 6400 imp/kWh"

Section 5.1.1 on page 41 describes the calibration procedure.

**edit**
Also had a look at the datasheet, and on the same page 20  Mike refers to there's this equation:

[image]

Channel 1 is the voltage sense channel, channel 0 is the current sense. Multiplied, including the current sense amplification you get instantaneous power. Input voltages are converted relative to a reference voltage, so you have to divide both channels by that (the denominator). HFc is a constant you can program by setting F0, F1 and F2, as per the table in Mike's answer (page 20 of the datasheet).

Note that this gives you a frequency proportional to power. Integrating this over time means counting periods of that frequency gives you a measure of consumed energy, and that's where the 3200 imp/kWh from the Reference Design User's Guide comes in.

**edit**
A concrete example. Let's suppose you want to measure energy of a 230 V/ 10 A device. Maximum input for the voltage channel is 660 mV, so we choose a 1:1000 divider for that. At a gain of 1 for the current channel maximum input voltage is 470 mV, so we can choose a 10 mΩ shunt for that, which gives us 10 mV/A. We use the internal Vref of 2.4 V, and set F0, F1 and F2 to 0. Then for a 230 V/ 10 A input we get

\$ HF_{OUT} = \dfrac{8.06 \times 230 mV \times 100 mV \times 1 \times 109.25 Hz}{(2.4 V)^2} = 3.516 Hz \$

That's for 2300 W, or 1.529 Hz per kW. For 1 kWh we'll have

\$ \text{pulse count} = 3600 s \times 1.529 Hz = 5503 \$

That's 5503 pulses/kWh.

Comment: Ok , so in MCU I will count a pulse then count the time till next pulse , this will be the power ???

Comment: I need to use this HFOUT to get a value from this chip , can you help ?? It's my graduation project ....will be delivered in 2 days & I'm stuck in this

Comment: The energy, not the power. Power is watts, energy is kWh. If it's calibrated at 3600 pulses/kWh, then a 1000 W load will generate these 3600 pulses in 1 hour, or 1 per second. A 500 W load will give 1 pulse per 2 seconds. And so on.

Comment: this is the device data sheet , http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22025a.pdf
what u saw was application note , .... sorry 
Is there something in the datasheet that shows the setting of hfout to imp/kwh ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If you could give me an example with number I will be grateful , if I used the above table f0=f1=f2 =0 , then the imp/kwh will be ?? & really really thanks you are saving my graduation !!

Comment: In that case you owe me a beer! :-) The table says a value of 109.25 Hz at a 3.58 MHz MCLK. HFOUT depends on the gain you'll be able to program, let's assume 10x, Vref you'll find in the datasheet, let's assume 1 V, then if both channels give you a hypothetical reading of 1 V you can calculate that HFOUT will be 8806 Hz.

Comment: Ok , I calcuated from datasheet :-
f0=f1-f2 =0 >>> HFC = 109.25
HFOUT = ( 8.06 * 1*1*1(gain ) *109.25)/(2.4*2.4) = 152 HZ 

so this will mean 152 imp /kwh :D , I really need this point & thanks from here to tomorrow

Comment: No, not 152 imp/kWh!! The value depends on the power the 1V for both input channels represents. If that would be 100 W for instance then 1 kWh = 10 hours x 100 W, and 10 hours = 36000 seconds x 152 imp/s, so 1 kWh = 5472000 pulses.

Comment: I totally lost ..! 
I don't know the voltage or current , but this chip gives me pulses from the pin Hfout which represents the average power , 
I can calculate the time interval between each two pulses ,so how to use this time interval to find current consumed power depending on this equation ?? :(

Comment: The values we used for current and voltage are read from the channel 0 and 1 inputs. Your circuitry will determine what their sensitivity is. For instance if you read the current across a 0.1 &Omega; shunt resistor you'll have 100 mV/A for that input. For the voltage input you'll need a resistor divider. If that divides by 100 you'll have 10 mV/V there. So multiplied you get (100 mV x 10 mV)/(1A x 1V) so per watt. The 100 mV and 10 mV go in your equation, we used 1 V and 1 V there. It's up to you to use that scaling factor to determine HFOUT. Do you understand the 5472000 pulses?

Comment: Yes ,yes :D thank you a lot , I got it 
so this is what the deferential channel means !  
thanks a lot :))) 
depending on my hardware I will determine the imp/kwh :)

Comment: if you could explain the 5472000 pulses , Till now it's working I get from the equation (digit) imp/instance == the current average power at this instance \

Comment: I added a concrete example with realistic values to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22025a.pdf) for the MCP3909 device has a table (table 4-3 on page 20) which shows how the HFout pin may be programmed with the F0, F1 & F2 pins for various sensitivities.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this

Comment: Is this related to imp/kwh some how ?